# Excel Query Versioning

Tags: sql, excel, version-control

Scenario - I have embedded a query into an excel workbook and distributed it to say 10 people in my company.  This workbook can also be found on a shared drive and is considered the master workbook.  Each of the 10 people make a, save as, copy with their own filters etc etc.  They can refresh the query as needed and everyone is happy.  2 months later, something changes in our tables and I need to update the query with additional code.  I can do so in the saved workbook on the shared drive but now all the 10 users copied versions of excel are still utilizing the old code.

How can I make their versions dependent on any changes to the embedded query in the "master" copy of the workbook?  Is this even possible?  If not and considering that embedded queries in excel are a company requirement, what is the best way to solve the problem I have described above?  We have SSRS but management wants to move away from that and prefers excel reporting.

Comment: Instead of the users making copies of the file, they should be connecting to the query as a data source.

Comment: Do you have any good instructional sources you can share?

Comment: I can see how to connect to tables and all, but not a saved query.

Comment: Yes, I will repost later tonight with addtl info.

Comment: Can't you use a VIEW in SQL and reference the VIEW instead of a table so you can just update the VIEW? On another note, moving from SSRS to Excel seems like a step backwards - they could just make a subscription with their filters and have it e-mailed whenevs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  In Excel, use the Get & Transform Data.  On the ribbon, select Data > Get Data > From File > From Workbook.  Then browse for the file containing the query and > Open.  Then a list of all of that file's tables/queries/parameters, etc will be displayed.  Select the query and then either Load, Load To or Transform.

Comment: You can also go to the Get & Transform Data group on the Data tab of the ribbon and select Get Data Using and Existing Connection and then Browse for your file.

Comment: I wrote a query in a workbook and that all worked out fine.  I then connected another file to that workbooks query and again, all fine there.  Problem is, the query in my "source" excel workbook pulls dynamic data and unless that workbook is opened and refreshed, it will always display the data it pulled last time the book was opened.  Looks like you do some macro tricks to open all files and refresh, but I really don't want to go down that route.  I tried the auto refresh built in excel feature but that only works when file is opened.

Comment: Any way around this?  I am thinking I might need to learn how to do a cube instead or go to the idea of creating a view for these types of excel query requests.